# Android Searchview gets refocused when returning from another fragment

Tags: android, searchview, android-jetpack-navigation

Currently using jetpack navigation and want to use a single activity. However, the `searchview` keeps regaining focus whenever I return from the card details back to the search, even though I have removed focus after clicking search. See [here](https://media.giphy.com/media/8KupFpmjthwZXnWJlL/giphy.gif).

What I'm currently doing to remove focus is I have a dummy view above my toolbar

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/database_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary" />

    <!-- Dummy view for receiving focus after SearchView clears focus -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/focus_dummy_view"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/database_toolbar" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
```

and after I perform a search, I do

```
searchView.clearFocus()
binding.focusDummyView.requestFocus()
```

My current workaround is to host the details in an activity, but I'd rather not. I made a new [project](https://github.com/1298se/android_searchview_navigation_bug) and still see this issue happening.

Some additional context is that this only occurred after updating to `"androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0"` from `1.2.5`. I raised this issue in the bug tracker but they have not responded to me yet. Wondering if anybody knows a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try

In Kotlin

```
     override fun onResume(){
        super.onResume()
        // Only runs if there is a view that is currently focused
        searchView.currentFocus?.let { view ->
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager
        imm?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
        searchView.clearFocus()

}
   
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! This still causes the keyboard to flicker as shown

Comment: I have edited the answer, please try that!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this two lines of code in your root layout xml.
To Clear focus from a View you can call getCurrentFocus().clearFocus() But remember that this will Simply move focus from current view to the first element in your view, not Completely removing focus from views; So if the first element in your layout is a EditText it's going to gain focus again.

A way to make sure your view doesn't get focus again is to add this attributes to your root view in your xml, enabling root view to capture focus.
To Clear focus from a View you can call getCurrentFocus().clearFocus() But remember that this will Simply move focus from current view to the first element in your view, not Completely removing focus from views; So if the first element in your layout is a EditText it's going to gain focus again.

A way to make sure your view doesn't get focus again is to add this attributes to your root view in your xml, enabling root view to capture focus

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

After that you need to clear focus from `onResume()`
I think it will help.